# MS Access 365 error - compact and repair error

Tags: ms-access, compact-database

I am suddenly receiving the below error message when attempting to compact and repair my access databases. Clicking ok on the error message results in original .accdb file being deleted and an .mdb being saved out. When entering the database I'm not in read only so I'm confused on what is happening.

Microsoft Access can't delete *accdb file path* after compacting it. The compacted database has been named *new mdb file path*

Answer (score 0):

When I have a database corruption that is not easily solved, I generally create a new, blank database, then import everything from the faulty db.
It's reasonably fast, and you can actually see and take note of which object fails to import. You can then import the problematic object(s) from your last backup.
Also: do all that stuff on a LOCAL drive, not a network drive. Network drives often are the culprit.

Comment: Thanks, it looks to be in fact a network issue as the database was on a shared disc (network). Issue went away so it appears to have been intermittent connection problem.